# How can I get textures to combine naturally in Half Life SDK?

Tags: textures

I'm quite new to Half Life SDK, the SDK dedicated to the original Half Life, and have mostly been testing my abilities by recreating certain scenes from Half Life 1 and its expansions.

One such scene is the starting room of Half Life: Opposing Force. It was going great until I reached the simple (or so I thought) desk. Image below.

[image: desk]

The desk in the game looks to be one unbreaking texture going around a corner without any pattern break too noticeable.

After resizing, repositioning, and doing other similar things to the textures I arrived at my current progress below after I made several rectangles with each one alternating by flipping the texture to try to get a smooth infinite loop of just part of the texture.

[image: more desk but this time its mine]

It repeats in the dark gray area on the right.

I have arrived at a mental dead end when it comes to how to get the corner to look natural and, while the repeat in the dark gray area is harder to notice, it is still noticeable and is made extra noticeable when there are bullet holes or blast marks on one of the creases.

So to sum up my question: How can I get my textures to appear unbreaking in a similar fashion to the game in Half Life SDK?

Comment: Have you tried using a world position alignment for the texture? If the texture has the same scale and rotation, the world position should make it align properly, no matter how your objects are connected.
See this entry: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Hammer_Face_Edit_Dialog

Comment: So far in my experience, whenever I have selected a face(s) of the desk (or any other object for that matter) the "World" and "Face" checkboxes are both permanently checked unless I align the texture to camera, in which case both are unchecked. Haven't gotten just one checked yet. As a bit of sidenote, I have also tried treating all of them as one along with the above options but that does not play well with the corner.